# Como seria "Já que vai à padaria, aproveita e passa na quitanda" em inglês?

Tags: tradução-inglês, palavra-para-ideia

Suponha que X diga a Y que vai à padaria. Y quer algo da quitanda, que é justamente o estabelecimento ao lado da padaria. Então Y responde a X:

> Já que vais à padaria, aproveite e passe na quitanda.

Como expressar em inglês essa frase, particularmente esse sentido de *aproveitar*?

O Google tradutor sugere algo péssimo:

> Since you go to the bakery, enjoy and pass in the grocery.

Consultei também o [dicionário Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/pt/dicionario/portugues-ingles/aproveitar) que dá algumas opções:

1. to enjoy
2. to make good use of
3. to use
4. avail
5. harness

Dentre elas, acho que a de número 2 seria a menos ruim, e eu tentaria

> Since you are going to the bakery, make good use of it and also go to the grocery.

Mas espero que haja algo melhor que isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O mais próximo que me ocorre é:

"Since you're going to the bakery, you might as well stop by the greengrocer's and bring/buy some..."

P.S.  O [**dicionário M.W.**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greengrocers) cita "greengrocer's" como "chiefly British". De fato, eu nunca vi algo que se assemelhasse a uma quitanda nos Estados Unidos.

> - [**"might as well"**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/might%20as%20well) - used to say that something should be done or accepted because it cannot be avoided **or because there is no good reason not to do it**

Comment: greengrocer is only BrE. In the States, we'd say the market here.

Answer (score 3):

Eu sugeriria:

> Since you're going to bakery, stop also by the grocery store.

Onde o sentido de "aproveitar a saída (para ir também noutro lugar)" está subtendido, pois não encontro nenhuma tradução direta de "aproveitar" que se encaixe bem nesse uso.

"Grocery store" não é exatamente "quitanda" - o inglês britânico tem "greengrocers", que é bem mais próxima, então essa pode ser uma opção, se a língua alvo da tradução for en-UK.

Alternativas ao "stop by" incluiriam "pass by", "go to", talvez "go by", etc.

Answer (score 1):

Um bom questionamento para responder sua pergunta seria: *aproveitar o que?*

[Aproveitar de](https://dicionario.priberam.org/aproveitar) algo, no caso uma oportunidade de já estar naquele local. Geralmente a gente acaba omitindo, talvez por ser algo natural ou implicito no nosso dia a dia.

> Já que vais à padaria, aproveita (a oportunidade) e passa na quitanda.

Não sei se o Google muda a tradução por usuário, mas a sugestão foi:

> Since you go to the bakery, take advantage and stop by the grocery store.

No entanto, [*take the opportunity* parece uma boa opção](https://www.linguee.com.br/ingles-portugues/traducao/take+the+opportunity.html). Veja que se remover *a oportunidade*, nas parte em português, o sentido geralmente se mantém. O mesmo ocorre com *take advantage*.

Pelo [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams), *take advantage* tem mais registros que *take the opportunity*. E *opportunity* aparece mais que *advantage*.

[*to seize*](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/seize) poderia talvez ser uma opção também.

No caso também, não seria uma tradução literal, considerando o contexto poderia também ser [*while you're at it*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/while%20%28one%27s%29%20at%20it), enquanto estiver por aí.

Para uma resposta mais precisa, caso não obtiver um resultado satisfatório, sugiro uma pergunta na [ELL (English Language Learners)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Eu diria que "take advantage" não funciona, e mesmo "take the opportunity" me parece de alguma forma exagerado, como "não perca a oportunidade" seria em português.

Comment: @stafusa Talvez tenha alguma nuance, minha percepção como estrangeiro também acha um tanto exagerado, adicionei mais um para ver se algum deles se encaixa, creio que soe mais natural.

Comment: A sua frase não funciona em inglês. aproveitar não se pode dizer de maneira solta assim em inglês.

Answer (score 1):

Esbarrei eu mesmo em uma forma que também se encaixa bem na situação.

> — I am going to the bakery.
> — You may as well go to the grocery **while you are at it**.

A entrada no dicionário [The Free Dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/while+you+are+at+it) traz outros exemplos (surpeendentemente) muito semelhantes a essa situação.

Comment: This is the only one that really works idiomatically.